# Deallocating memory with destructor in Fortran

Tags: memory-management, constructor, fortran, valgrind, destructor

**Basis:** i am trying to write good code in Fortran, using constructors and destructors.
Here is an example of very simple `Test` class and it's client:

```
module test_class_module
implicit none

type :: Test
private
integer, allocatable :: arr(:)
 CONTAINS
    final :: destructor
end type

interface Test
    procedure :: constructor
end interface

 CONTAINS
    function constructor(arr_size) result(this)
        type(Test) :: this
        integer, intent(in) :: arr_size
        write(*,*) 'Constructor works'
        allocate(this % arr(arr_size))
    end function

    subroutine destructor(this)
        type(Test) :: this
        write(*,*) 'Destructor works'
        if (ALLOCATED(this % arr)) deallocate(this % arr)
    end subroutine        
end module

program test_client
    use test_class_module

    type(Test) :: tst
    tst = Test(100)
end
```

**Problem:**
I run it with `valgrind` and it printed:

```
Constructor works
Destructor works
Destructor works
==22229== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22229== in use at exit: 432 bytes in 2 blocks
==22229== total heap usage: 10 allocs, 8 frees, 13,495 bytes allocated
```

**Question:** why memory is still allocated? (P.S. I understand need of assignment operator for proper class use, but it is not sufficient for this question) Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the destructor should not be called for `tst` at the end of the program. According to the latest standard the main program variables are implicitly `save`d. Therefore, it should only call the `destructor` for the function result on rhs and for the `tst` when it is being overwritten in the assignment.

Comment: Doesn't the `save` attribute prevent finalization only at `end`, rather than the case where `tst` is finalized as the lhs for the intrinsic assignment?  So, two finalizations should result?

Comment: Yes, the point was it is not finalized at the end and the array remains allocated. Similar: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/271088

Comment: Ah yes, I understand your point now.  `tst` is finalized once, but crucially not at the end.  [I was confused by "the destructor should not be called for `tst`".]

Comment: So, the answer is: "destructors work well, but not for main program. Memory leak in this case it is ok." Yes?

Comment: Exactly, you must call the finalizers yourself for variables defined in the main program and for module variables.

Comment: Also note that the behavior of `final` is not fully implemented across all compilers (e.g. ifort -- yes, gcc -- needs 4.9.x but final is not called for all cases it should be).

Comment: It is very strange situation. So, for main and for any module variables i should explicitly use construction `call destructor(tst)`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Or just let the operating systems to clean the memory, if there are no other important features to by done in the finalizer.

Comment: Therefore, constructor works correctly only for procedures. What idea is covered under such behaviour? Is it just temporary bugs or we should live with it? (I understand that it is hard question)

Comment: You must ask the authors of the standard http://www.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/ and http://www.j3-fortran.org I don't know. It is not a temporary bug, it is the standard behavior.

Answer (score 2):

For posterity.
You would see the desired behaviour if you wrapped your three lines in your test program in a `BLOCK`. I modified your main program only:

```
program test_client
    use test_class_module
    write(*,*) '1 program start'
    BLOCK
        type(Test) :: tst
        write(*,*) '2 calling constructor'
        tst = Test(100)
        write(*,*) '3 block ending'
    END BLOCK
    write(*,*) '4 program end'
end
```

This produces:

```
valgrind bin/SimpleTest
==10031== Memcheck, a memory error detector
...
1 program start
2 calling constructor
Constructor works
3 block ending
Destructor works
4 program end
==10031== 
==10031== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10031==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10031==   total heap usage: 22 allocs, 22 frees, 12,417 bytes allocated
==10031== 
==10031== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==10031== 
==10031== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10031== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```